# Azure Data Factory Copy Data dynamically get last blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Pipeline that runs on a Blob Created Trigger, I want it to grab the last Blob added and copy that to the desired location.

How do I dynamically generate the file path for this outcome?

- [System Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables)
- [Expressions and Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions)
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**@triggerBody().folderPath**" and "**@triggerBody().fileName**" captures the last created blob file path in event trigger. You need to map your pipeline parameter to these two trigger properties. Please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#map-trigger-properties-to-pipeline-parameters) to do the parameter passing and reference. Thanks.

Comment: Activity Applicant Blob to Applicant Table failed:  'The template language expression 'triggerBody().fileName' cannot be evaluated because property 'fileName' doesn't exist, available properties are 'DataFactory, Pipeline, RunId, RunToken, TriggerType, TriggerId, TriggerName, TriggerTime, TriggerCallbackUri, RunAttempt, parameters'.

Comment: ^ I have the Trigger watching the correct Blob path, path starting with and ending with appropriate "data/{@triggerBody().fileName}.csv" < not actually what the trigger setup looks like but is representative... and @triggerBody().fileName is not available?

Comment: Hi, please don't directly refer "@triggerBody().fileName" or  "@triggerBody().folderPath" in dataset. You should: 1. define dataset parameter and refer it to the dataset fileName/folderPath, 2.Define pipeline parameters and pass them to the dataset parameter, 3.Pass "@triggerBody().folderPath" and "@triggerBody().fileName" to pipeline parameters when trigger the pipeline run. This link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#map-trigger-properties-to-pipeline-parameters  gives you more details.