# Copy latest files from S3 to Azure Blob (using Azure Factory V2)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

I'm still new to Azure Data Factory and am trying to move files that are dumped in my S3 folder/bucket daily to Azure blob. I already created datasets (for source and sink) and linked services in Data Factory.

But since my S3 bucket receives new file every day, I'm wondering how to move **the latest file that was dropped in the S3 (say at 5am EST) on a daily basis**. I have looked through most of the answers online like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989698/copy-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-aws-s3), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334901/azure-data-factory-copy-data-dynamically-get-last-blob), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074516/incrementally-copy-s3-to-azure-blob) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340763/1330974). But none of them explains how to figure out which is the latest file in S3 (maybe **based on last modified date/time or by matching the file name pattern that goes like this 'my_report_YYYYMMDD.csv.gz'**) and only copy that file to the destination blob.

Thank you in advance for your help/answer!

Answer (score 1):

My idea as below:

1.Firstly,surely,configure your pipeline execution in the schedule trigger.Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger).

2.Use [Get metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#next-steps) ,which supports Amazon S3 Connector,to get the files in your S3 dataset.

[image]

Get the last modified and file name etc. metadata.

[image]

3.Put these metadata array which contains lastModified Time and file name into a [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#request-payload-schema) or [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity). In that rest api or function method,you could do a sort logical business to get the latest modified file.

4.Get the fileName from Web Activity or Azure Function Activity ,then copy it into Azure Blob Storage.

Another idea is using [Custom-Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities).You could implement your requirements with .net code.

Answer (score 1):

(Side note: thanks to Jay Gong above for suggesting a solution)

I found the answer. It's simpler than I expected. There's `dynamic content/expression` that we can add to 'Filter by last modified' field of the S3 dataset. Please see the screenshot below where I show how I picked files that are no more than 5 hours old by using dynamic expression. More about these expressions can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

[image]

Hope this is helpful.